# how i can retrieving result from mysql in array?

Tags: java, android, mysql, arrays, json

I want to get results from the database as an array. I have a table "commande" where I have stock. I want to get stock as an array. Something like this: `array[0],array[],array[2]`
This is  the structure of my table commande `(idfichecmd    idproduit   idclt   qte     datecmd)`

This is my code:

```
String response = null;
String res = "";
//the year data to send
ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("",));   
try {
    Log.i("","<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<TRY");      
    response = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost("http://0.0.0.0/GetCmdDetails.php",nameValuePairs); 
    res=response.toString();
    // res = res.trim();
    //res= res.replaceAll("\\s+","");
    //error.setText(res);

} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.i("","<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<Catch");
}

//parse json data
try{
    JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(res);
    //-----------------------------------------
    //nom= new String[jArray.length()];
    //prenom= new String[jArray.length()];
    //----------------------------------------
    for (int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++) {
        JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i)
```

Comment: where you have specified database connection?

Comment: What is returned in your http post request?

Comment: return just the frist field in table

Comment: can you post the string that is actually returned and the code which produces it?

Comment: $sql=mysql_query ("SELECT qte FROM commande WHERE idfichecmd = '$id'");
$output = array();
  while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
   { $output[]=$row;}
     print(json_encode($output));

Comment: after in java code i want to put everey stock field in textview

Comment: Ok, what is the content of `res` and `jArray` in your java code?

Answer (score 0):

First, test if your query is giving the correct result.

I use this solution for getting the jsonarray:

Use HttpClient to call the webservice.

```
private List<NameValuePair> parameters;

    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(//yoururl);
    int statusCode = -1;
    try {
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(this.parameters));
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

 //Get your inputstream here and convert it to json after

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader
                        (new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
```

Comment: no , i can get the result but i get the last number in field sotck

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what you mean by that.

Comment: i get the result in my database the problem there it is how i get my result in array something like this array[0],array[1]...

Comment: I tested your PHP code on my server. I use echo json_encode, I  changed echo to print and it failed. Try using echo?

Comment: in my application I have 5 textview I want to load it from the return result 
Each number represents a textview

Comment: (Forget about my echo/print stuff). What are you receiving in your Android app? Can you get the json string?

Comment: mysql_fetch_assoc should be mysql_fetch_array, try that.

Comment: $id = $_POST["idcmdBase"];
$sql=mysql_query ("SELECT qte FROM commande WHERE idfichecmd = '$id'");
$output = array();
  while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)var_dump($row));
   { $output[]=$row;}
     print(json_encode($output));

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in C:\wamp\www\getStock.php on while

Comment: $id is a string or integer? If integer remove the '' So:
$sql=mysql_query ("SELECT qte FROM commande WHERE idfichecmd = " . $id);